# Gmaps4Rails default zoom setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm having problem with zooming the map to country level. My map is displaying fine however, I want the default map to fill the page with the view of UK instead of the whole world when i first view the page. Is that possible? Thanks

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
      marker.lat user.latitude
      marker.lng user.longitude
      marker.infowindow user.description
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map-canvas'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>)
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds(markers);
    if(navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;
  });
});
</script>
```

Update:

I got it working by adding `handler.getMap().setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(54, 0.3));`

Answer (score 0):

Hey when you can load map using gmaps4rails just add option for showing your location on load using options as `center_latitude` and `center_longitude` . i have set it simply by using following code. i have used hypothetical values here. if you are using gmaps4rails then you have no need to manually defined  javascript. just add this lines of code in you HTML.erb file. it will automatically add your markers according to your json.

```
 <%= gmaps("map_options" => {"auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 8,
    "center_latitude" =>'9999999',
    "center_longitude" => '90909890',
    "auto_adjust" => true,
    "auto_zoom" => true},"markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list","rich_marker" => true , "custom_infowindow_class" => "yellow" } }) %>
```

Comment: it gives me error saying undefined method `gmaps' for #<#<Class:0x007f9fa617b680>. Any idea? I got the gmaps column for users

Comment: offcource in your index.html.erb

Comment: i think you need to refer https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/DRY-example for properflow and for given issue look in this thread https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/41